# Semicircle in TikZ using start and end points instead of angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I need a semicircle in TikX starting at (x1, y1), ending at (x2, y2), assuming that the circle is centered at (cx, cy) and has a radius r.

For instance:

(x1, y1) = (0.25598, 0.8256)

(x2, y2) = (0.3870, 0.7221)

(cx, cy) = (0.5, 1)

r = 0.3

Most of the examples use angles but not points.

Comment: Check tkzEuclide package, mainly the \tkzDrawArc command. It does just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the answer of [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2.5598,8.256);
  \coordinate (B) at (3.870,7.221);

  \coordinate (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);

  \draw[fill=red] (A) circle [radius=2pt];
  \draw[fill=blue] (B) circle [radius=2pt];
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
  \let\StartAngle\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
  \let\EndAngle\pgfmathresult

  \draw[fill=green] (C) circle [radius=2pt];

  \draw (A) let \p1 = ($(C) - (A)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)}
  in 
  arc [start angle=\StartAngle, end angle=\EndAngle, radius=\n1];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The angles can be calculated via `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (.5, 1);
  \coordinate (p1) at (.25598, .8256);
  \coordinate (p2) at (.3870, .7221);
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{c}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{p1}{center}}
  \let\StartAngle\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{c}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{p2}{center}}
  \let\EndAngle\pgfmathresult
  \draw (p1) arc[start angle=\StartAngle, end angle=\EndAngle, radius=.3];
  \fill[radius=.5pt, red] (p2) circle[] (p1) circle[] (c) circle[];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]